# Failure: DNS resolution failed: DNS response error code NXDOMAIN on AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ip-address, cname, amazon-route53

I have a site hosted on AWS and recently the site went down with NXDOMAIN error. The site was working before and the issue doesn't appear to be with the site as the Elastic Beanstalk direct link (xxxx-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com) is working fine.

In my Route53 I have a CNAME linking to my (xxxx-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com) and a SOA and 4 NS records supplied by AWS. xxxx is a placeholder for the actual site name. Running dig...

```
    dig xxxx.com any

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> xxxx.com any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 63003
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxxx.com.          IN  ANY

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.            895 IN  SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1435723016 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 64.71.255.204#53(64.71.255.204)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 30 23:57:22 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 102
```

It looks like my NS records might be the issue but I am not sure. Can someone confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: you need to contact your registar to figure out what's happening with the domains. You've left the domain in the question so I actually tried looking at what DNS was seeing for it.

**Do you have an A record for your domain?**

```
host vizibyl.com
Host vizibyl.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

https://www.whois.net ->

```
Name Server: NS-1519.AWSDNS-61.ORG
Name Server: NS-1828.AWSDNS-36.CO.UK
Name Server: NS-228.AWSDNS-28.COM
Name Server: NS-544.AWSDNS-04.NET
Status: clientHold http://www.icann.org/epp#clientHold
Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
```

http://www.icann.org/epp#clientHold
for clientHold:

This status code tells your domain's registry to not activate your domain in the DNS and as a consequence, it will not resolve. It is an uncommon status that is usually enacted during legal disputes, non-payment, or when your domain is subject to deletion.

Often, this status indicates an issue with your domain that needs resolution. If so, you should contact your registrar to resolve the issue. If your domain does not have any issues, but you need it to resolve, you must first contact your registrar and request that they remove this status code.

Comment: Got it! The domain contact info was never verified that the registrant email is reachable. "If we don't receive verification within 15 days after you registered the domain, we must suspend the domain as required by ICANN regulations. The domain will no longer be accessible on the Internet." The email comes from noreply@domainnameverification.net